# Replacing a jquery function with my own (wording?)

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

Didn't know how to word this better and couldn't find an answer through some searches.

I'm just wondering if I can replace: `$("#someid").hover(function() {});` with my own function in place such as: `$("#someid").hover(myfunction() {});`

This has probably been answered and I'm just terrible at searching but any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Do you simply mean: `$("someid").hover(myfunction)`? Where your function is defined elsewhere? Just supply the function name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure you can...

```js
$('#someID').hover(myFunc);

function myFunc() {
    $('#someID').css('color','red');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="someID">HOVER ME</div>
```

Comment: That's the opposite, `.on('hover'` is deprecated (removed?) but not `.hover()` shorthand for `mouseenter/mouseleave` events

Comment: Appreciate it, just wanting to make sure and couldn't find anything on it. . Thank you